# In Android OS what code do I use to set a ringback tone (waitone)?

Tags: android, waitone

I need my app to be able to change the ringback tone (The sound the other side hears when calling me, the funtone or waitone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. This is set by your carrier, and not by the device.

Comment: But I can buy fun tones and set them manually on my device, so can't I do the same with my app?

Comment: @Rami Not unless your carrier offers an API for it

Comment: I'm so glad this isn't possible.

Comment: @kcoppock Agreed. It'd be so easy for carrier to pay off some dev to make an app that automatically does this every now and then, and make loads of money off users (how many of us call ourselves up?). They can always blame it on the dev later.

Comment: @Rami You can buy and set ringtones (what you hear when someone calls you) on your device, but you cannot change the tone that other people hear when they call you.

Comment: So how come there are applications that offers the ability to change the ringback tone? e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mnc.moblife.hitsRbt&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tbmMubW9ibGlmZS5oaXRzUmJ0Il0.

Comment: @rami as you can see from the ratings it doesn't work in most countries. And android still doesn't have an API for this. The app must be using a carrier API.